# Foundation 5 and accordion

Tags: accordion

I'm using the Foundation 5 framework and trying to use the accordion.

If I use the sample code all ok: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/accordion.html

If I try to use div tags and / or sectin in place of tag dl and dd does not work

Why?

Answer (score 0):

Because the accordion code is with hardcoded tag names :) ... and you can't even configure them.

This is part of the accordion code:

```
........
  .on('click.fndtn.accordion', '[' + this.attr_name() + '] dd > a', function (e) {
    var accordion = S(this).closest('[' + self.attr_name() + ']'),
        target = S('#' + this.href.split('#')[1]),
        siblings = S('dd > .content', accordion),
        aunts = $('> dd', accordion),
        settings = accordion.data(self.attr_name(true) + '-init'),
        active_content = S('dd > .content.' + settings.active_class, accordion),
        active_parent = S('dd.' + settings.active_class, accordion);
........
```

You can see the `dd` and `dl` tag names inside :) ... but - of course - you can make them configurable :) ...